huggingface model inference: ERROR: Flag 'minloglevel' was defined more than once (in files 'src/error.cc' and ..)
I'm trying to use llama 3.1 70b from huggingface(end goal is to quantize it and deploy it in amazon sagemaker), but I'm facing:

ERROR: Flag 'minloglevel' was defined more than once (in files
'src/error.cc' and
'home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/abseil-split_1720857154496/work/absl/log/flags.cc').

The code is super simple (quantization not applied yet), but I cannot make it work (originally I was using a notebook and the kernel died, after exporting the code to python file and running it in the command line I found the error mentioned previously).
import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, BitsAndBytesConfig, AutoTokenizer
model_id = "meta-llama/Llama-3.1-8B"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
model_id,
device_map="auto"
)
input_text = """<|begin_of_text|><|start_header_id|>user<|end_header_id|>Translate the following English text to French:
'Hello, how are you?'<|eot_id|><|start_header_id|>assistant<|end_header_id|>"""
input_ids = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt").to("cuda")
print(input_ids)
output = model.generate(**input_ids, max_new_tokens=10)

I have tried both the 70b and 8b versions, but none worked (so I know it is not something specific to 70). I have a feeling that this is related to package conflicts or similar and not necessarily the models.

Where exactly does the error pop up? Please update the question with the full error trace.

Thanks.The error pop up in the last line of the code I sent, and what I posted in the question is the whole error message(no error  trace).

I faced this issue with my studio space on SageMaker, too.
This is a compatibility issue when using sentencepiece v0.2.0 with the latest transformers version.
I solved this problem by downgrading sentencepiece to 0.1.99.

you can also use pip install --no-deps sentencepiece==0.1.99 to prevent the other dependencies from being modified and causing other side effects which I faced on SageMaker :/
